# EditText counterEnabled but for Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Is there equivalent solution for Compose for tag counterEnabled? Like here

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/til_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:counterEnabled="true"
    app:counterMaxLength="50">
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/et_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the support text:

```
val maxChar = 50

TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = {
        if (it.length <= maxChar) text = it
    },
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    supportingText = {
        Text(
            text = "${text.length} / $maxChar",
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            textAlign = TextAlign.End,
        )
    },
)
```

make sure you use M3.
[Material 3 - Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#textfield)